# Invalid XML: Error on line 6: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>"

Tags: java

When I am using [rome](https://github.com/rometools/rome) to parse a xml link:

```
package com.dolphin.soa.post;

import com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.rometools.rome.io.ParsingFeedException;
import com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.rometools.rome.io.XmlReader;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * @author dolphin
 */
@Slf4j
public class MiniExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedInput().build(new XmlReader(new URL("http://yechengfu.com/feed.xml")));
        } catch (ConnectException connectException) {
            log.error("rss parse error", connectException);
        } catch (ParsingFeedException e){
            log.error("rss parse error", e);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("rss parse error", e);
        }
    }

}
```

shows the error `Invalid XML: Error on line 6: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".` I check the xml link, and did not find any non-standard format. why would this happend and is it possbile to fix it? This is my dependencies:

```
api "com.rometools:rome:1.15.0"
```

Comment: That URL yields a 308 (a redirect) to https://yechengfu.com/feed.xml (instead of HTTP). A redirect isn't followed but it tries to parse the HTML. Switch to https to get the actual feed.

Comment: The file parsed is not valid XML even if the URL says so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file that is returned from calling "http://yechengfu.com/feed.xml" is a small html file (with a single `<hr>` tag):

```html
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see this if you run a command like curl:

```sh
curl http://yechengfu.com/feed.xml
```

The page is redirected in a normal browser, but curl and XmlReader will not follow redirects automatically. If you give curl the "-L" argument it will follow to you `feed.xml` file.

I guess that you will have to read up on how to configure nginx and use it as a reverse proxy instead of rewrite the URL.